# Expansion of Wilson loop operator to obtain the field tensor in non-Abelian gauge theory

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, wilson-loop

I am reading Prof. Eduardo Fradkin's QFT lecture note (the link to the lecture note is gone). In his note, he considered the Wilson loop operator
\begin{equation}
\hat{W}_{\Gamma(x,x)}=\hat{P} \left( \exp{ig\oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z)} \right)
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma(x,x)$ denotes a loop with both its initial and final points at $x$, $g$ is the coupling constant, and $A_{\mu}$ is the non-Abelian gauge field. We want to obtain the definition of the field tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$ by expanding $W_{\Gamma(x,x)}$ to the leading order when we have infinitesimal $\Gamma(x,x)$. This means the length of the loop $\Gamma(x,x)$ is infinitesimal and also the oriented surface whose boundary is $\Gamma(x,x)$ has its minimal area infinitesimal. We then proceed as follows
\begin{equation}
\hat{W}_{\Gamma(x,x)} \approx \hat{P} \left( 1 + ig\oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) + \frac{1}{2} \left[ ig\oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) \right]^{2} + \cdots \right).
\end{equation}
The first two terms are easy to do via Stoke's theorem:
\begin{align}
& \hat{P} \left( 1\right) = 1 \\
& \hat{P} \left( ig\oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) \right) = ig\oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) = \frac{ig}{2} \int_{\Sigma} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} \left( \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} \right).
\end{align}
My question is that he then directly wrote down
\begin{align}
\hat{P} \left( \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) \right]^{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} \left( -\left[A_{\mu},A_{\nu} \right] \right).
\end{align}
**I am a bit confused about how can we turn the path-ordered product of two line integrals into something like a surface integral.** I currently do not have an idea about where to start to prove this identity. But it seems to be crucial if we want to prove that, for infinitesimal loop $\Gamma(x,x)$, we have
\begin{align}
\hat{W}_{\Gamma(x,x)} \approx 1 + \frac{ig}{2}\int_{\Sigma} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} -ig[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}].
\end{align}
Are there any suggestions to carry out this computation
\begin{align}
\hat{P} \left( \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \oint_{\Gamma(x,x)}dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z) \right]^{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu} \left( -\left[A_{\mu},A_{\nu} \right] \right)
\end{align}
in details?

Comment: Looks to me like something is misplaced there. The $\left[ A, A \right]$ term should be the typical non-Abelian YM "tail" of the 2-form. If that's the case, $$\omega=dz^{\mu}A_{\mu}(z)$$, and $$d\omega=\frac{1}{2}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}\left(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}-\left[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}\right]\right)$$ (check me for missing factors), and direct application of Stokes theorem should lead you there. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I think the application of Stoke's theorem for your $\omega$ only gives us the $\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$? If I denote the 1-form $A = A_{\mu} dz^{\mu}$, then the RHS of your $d\omega$ will be $dA -ig A \wedge A$? For example, see the section "differential form" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field_strength_tensor. I guess the main point here might be that for non-abelian gauge field we can not stop at the first order expansion, the next order expansion (in terms of small loop) will be in the same order as well. Just my thought.